# Genetic Algorithm questions

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I am working on a basic Genetic algorithm in Java with a population of 20 chromosomes, I plan on keeping the top 20% of the parent population for the next generation, my question is in regards to creating the next generation  after the strongest of the current generation has been found, are the new generation of children created based around the possibility of Crossover and Mutation of the parents? Or are the next generation of children randomly generated again but with the strongest previous parents kept.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting, but I don't see the connection with Java.

Comment: @Rami So how do you want this biology question to be related to Java?

Comment: @laune The algorithm is Java based

Comment: but it's not a Java question, it's a computing science question.  There's a forum for that ->  http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For questions regarding how GA works, I would say you have picked the wrong place to ask your question

Comment: @user3437460 FYI, this is not a biology question. Take a loot at the tag [genetic-algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/genetic-algorithm/info)

Answer (score 0):

For the next generation it's reasonable to have all 3 based on probabilities.

Crossover will get you closer to the desired solution.

Mutations try to ensure you don't get stuck on a local optimum.

New entries can help avoid local optimum, or help explore new areas of the search space when the search space is too vast for the initial population to correctly represent. This is most useful for the first few generations but after a while they will always be outperformed by the previous generation.

There's no golden answer and you need to try out and experiment with various strategies and optimizations to get it to work for your problem. Try to log and analyze how each strategy is working and adjust your parameters (i.e. if you see mutations get always killed in the next round you can take them out or lower their ratio).